# Fancybox, when I open group of images and click on next with using “start index” - it's not working normally

Tags: jquery, fancybox

When I open group of images with fancybox "Index of start", I have a problem.

//"img[2]"  it's img with rel=2

When I click on img, it's opens.
After load, when I click "prev Img" - it's working normally,
but on click "next img" - Gallery start playing from img[0].
using fancyBox v2.0.3.
in action:
http://youtu.be/1dii1qC9cOM

HTML:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li>
        <a rel="0" data-fancybox-group="PHOTOGALLERY"> <img alt="" src="1.jpg"> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a rel="1" data-fancybox-group="PHOTOGALLERY"> <img alt="" src="2.jpg"> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a rel="2" data-fancybox-group="PHOTOGALLERY"> <img alt="" src="3.jpg"> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a rel="3" data-fancybox-group="PHOTOGALLERY"> <img alt="" src="4.jpg"> </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
// Using group of images, received from ajax
    var hrefList = new Array;
    for (var i in data) {
      hrefList[i] = data[i].PATH
    }    
    ul.find('a').live('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var himself = $(this);
      $.fancybox( hrefList, {
        'index': himself.attr('rel')
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.live()` with fancybox v2.x since it already handles present and future (dynamically added) elements. Additionally fancybox uses either `data-fancybox-group` or `rel` to group images within a gallery of existing elements but since you are creating a *manual* gallery from `array`, you don't actually need either of them so you html can be as simple like (even you wouldn't need the `<a>` tag but let's leave it like that):

```
<ul class="gallery">
 <li>
  <a><img alt="" src="1.jpg" /></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a><img alt="" src="2.jpg" /></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a><img alt="" src="3.jpg" /></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a><img alt="" src="4.jpg" /></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Then, in order to get the right `index` for each thumbnail you may tweak your js like:

```
var hrefList = new Array;
for (var i in data) {
 hrefList[i] = data[i].PATH
} 
$("ul.gallery a").each(function(e){
 $(this).click(function(){
  $.fancybox( hrefList, {
   index: e,
   type: 'image'    
  }); //fancybox        
 });//click
});//each
```

that will always give you the gallery that starts with the right `index`.

Notice that you don't need `preventDefault()` either since there isn't any `href` set for each anchor