# how do I open fancybox using the specific index of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, indexing, fancybox

I am using fancybox with the below code

```
$("a[rel=Fancy" + UserId + "].Items").fancybox({ 'autoscale': 'false',
        'cyclic': true,
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'titlePosition': 'over',
        'titleFormat': function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
            return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
        }
    });

$("a[rel=Fancy" + UserId + "].Items:first").click();
```

it opens fancybox, but it starts showing the images from the first index. I want to start fancybox on the image which the user will clicks on...

How do I to give the index in fancybox?

Comment: HOw will you get the index ? where is your click event handler ?

Comment: you don't need to pass any `index`, fancybox will just open the target image set on the `href` of the link you click, unless you have a handler that modify such default behavior.

Comment: I have the same question, as I'm by-passing click events in my mobile app!

Answer (score 1):

```
var hrefList = new Array;
for (var i in data) {
    hrefList[i] = data[i].PATH
} 
$("ul.gallery a").each(function(e){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $.fancybox( hrefList, {
            index: e,
            type: 'image'    
        }); //fancybox        
    });//click
});//each
```

Source: [Fancybox, when I open group of images and click on next with using “start index” - it's not working normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683826/fancybox-when-i-open-group-of-images-and-click-on-next-with-using-start-index)